# Overring touchesEnded in SKSpriteNode - check if any node in scene is under point

Tags: sprite-kit, skspritenode

I've had to override touchesBegan and touchesEnded in an SKSpriteNode subclass that has children nodes (because I want to propagate a touch event on the child node)

touchesBegan is working fine, but the problem I'm having is in touchesEnded checking that the same sprite is still under a users finger.

No matter what I try I never get a reference to 'self' in the node list of places at that point

```
 override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        print("touched ended")
        for t in touches {
            let allNodes = nodes(at: t.location(in: self.scene!))
            print(allNodes)
        }
    }
```

Should t.location(in: self.scene!) return what I'm looking for? I've also tried self.scene?.view but this also returns an empty node list.

How could I go about checking that the touchesEnded touch was still on this SKSpriteNode? or indeed if they have moved their finger check if it's over an entirely different node? I guess I need to convert this back to the whole scene coordinates some how which I thought t.location(in: self.scene.view)) would do. My other thought was using some kind of delegate method on the main scene file, but would the touch.location be relative to the node that was tapped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're checking nodes in `self`.. self here IS the subclassed parent node.. You should check for nodes in your main scene, which would show the subclassed node properly:

`let allNodes = self.scene!.nodes(at: t.location(in: self.scene!))`

You can also use the various `convert` and `convertPoint` methods to do this.

Comment: I know self is the subclassed node, but shouldn't location in self.scene then return the location in the scene? As scene should be the scene this node is contained in the allNodes line.

Comment: oh I missed that. let me try that out.

Comment: sorry the foo bit was confusing as I was trying to debug what the coordinates were. I've edited the question to make it more obvious

Comment: fixed it:

`let allNodes = self.scene!.nodes(at: t.location(in: self.scene!))
` @TommyBs

Comment: @TommyBs you were calling your subclass` method `nodes()` instead of the scene's `nodes()` .. :P Which is exactly what I said, but I still missed that  part haha. XD

Comment: Yeah thanks I realise that now! Now I just have the problem of the touch finishes on the child node of the subclass rather than the subclass itself I need to loop through all the nodes. But not a biggie. Thanks for your help

Comment: @TommyBs np. if you need help w that post up a new q and ping me here. im free right now and bored so.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132947/discussion-between-tommybs-and-fluidity).